# QGIS: Export multiple points layers to Excel

Tags: qgis, pyqgis

I am trying to export multiple points layers to separate Excel files. I could do it manually but since I have 500+ points layers it would take too long. Is there any Python code to solve this?

Comment: Multiple point layers? How are you exporting them manually?

Comment: By right clicking > save object as

Comment: A simple way without python is to merge them first to one layer and then export. If thats an option for you.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. But they need to be separate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should export all vector layers added to the table of contents to excel files:

```
import os
output_folder = r'C:\GIS\data\testdata'

options = QgsVectorFileWriter.SaveVectorOptions()
options.driverName = "xlsx"

for lyr in QgsProject.instance().mapLayers().values():
    if isinstance(lyr, qgis._core.QgsVectorLayer):
        path = os.path.join(output_folder,lyr.name()+'.xlsx')
        QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormatV2(lyr, path, QgsCoordinateTransformContext() ,options)
```