# PyQGIS export layers to CSV

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, export, csv

This code exports all layers starting with xxx_ to CSV format. But all fields are exported as string. How can I export the fields with numbers as integer or double?

```
#
#https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/372890/qgis-export-multiple-points-layers-to-excel/372891#372891
import os, time, csv
Start = time.time()
#expFolder = r'C:\GIS\data\testdata'#anpassen
expFolder = r"/home/cirrusklaus/Downloads/tmp/csv"
preFix ='xxx_'
options = QgsVectorFileWriter.SaveVectorOptions()
options.driverName = "csv"#anpassen

for lyr in QgsProject.instance().mapLayers().values():
    if lyr.name().startswith(preFix) and isinstance(lyr, qgis._core.QgsVectorLayer):
        QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormatV3(lyr, path, QgsCoordinateTransformContext() ,options)
        path = os.path.join(expFolder,lyr.name()+'.csv')

Ende = time.time()
print("Das ganze hat " + str(round(Ende-Start,2))+" Sek. gedauert")
```

Comment: CSV's are text files and therefore support only strings. However, you can create a CSVT which a sidecar file that contains designations for the data types of the fields. See [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/38853/128665). It depends what you want to use your CSV for, but be aware that not all software support CSVT's.

Comment: use `qgis.core.QgsVectorLayer` instead of `qgis._core.QgsVectorLayer`

Comment: @Taras thx for your advice

Comment: Please, do not forget about ["What should I do when someone answers my question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormatV3 object recognizes the field properties

```
Layer= iface.activeLayer()
expFolder = r"/home/cirrusklaus/Downloads/tmp/csv/" #adjust
Name= 'Tabexport3'#adjust 
Filetyp='csv'#adjust  csv, xlsx, ods
layers = QgsProject.instance().mapLayers().values()
fileName = f"{Name}.{Filetyp}"

output = os.path.join(expFolder, fileName)
options = QgsVectorFileWriter.SaveVectorOptions()
options.driverName = Filetyp
options.fileEncoding = "UTF-8"
QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormatV3(Layer, output,QgsCoordinateTransformContext() ,options)
```